# What is the best PDF generating tool to use when creating large amounts of PDF (80k) every two weeks?

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf-generation, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I need to create a console application that will generate 80k or so PDFs every two weeks. This app will be triggered using Window's Task Scheduler. I tried testing with the LocalReport object in .NET and it crashed in the 700 mark :(. I'm really new to .NET and I would really appreciate your inputs on this. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Open source tool only.

Comment: You need to add more detail to the question. Do you already have the app to produce the pdf or you just have the data in the DB and are looking for a report generator? Detail like this.

Comment: Hi Paulo. I'm still at the designing stage. All I have is the data in the database. Thanks for replying.

Comment: If you go open source I recomend itextsharp (I'm one of the developers) depending on the usage it may be free or not. There are lots of info on how to produce tables and other reports on it. If the license is ok give it a try and come back with more focused questions.

Answer (score 1):

We are using **ABCpdf** at the moment for producing about 100k+ pdf every other week. We use HTML as a template. 
ABCpdf does the job well, although there are some things you need to be aware of:

1. Keep in mind that ABCpdf is single threaded. In a distributed environment you need to handle it as any other single threaded process.
2. It will take longer to process the bigger pictures you try to embed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer user1571242. I'm sorry I did not mention earlier but I need an open source tool for this. iTextSharp seem popular but I'm not quite sure if this is the best tool to generate as many pdfs as I need to.

Comment: Does it have to be OSS? Or is free sufficient? If it is enough for it to be free I would give nReco (http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx) a try.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Hansen. I will check out NReco. In the meantime, I will keep this question open until I find the suitable tool. I really appreciate you helping me out.